# Double border that fits heading and container

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a solution to create a two color border for a heading. The first part of the border should cover the heading while the second part of the border first the rest of the container.

I'm currently using the following markup and styling:

```
<h4 class="title"><span>This is a heading</span></h4>

h4.title span{
border-bottom: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}

h4.title{
border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

This almost get the desired result besides the fact that the borders are now below each other and not next to each other.

Already tried to solve it with `:after` but this border never shows up, probably due to the `display: block` of the heading

Comment: `display: block` of the heading shouldn't affect display of `:after`. Probably `:after` had zero size or the `content` property was missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative `margin-bottom`, like:

```
h4.title span{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
h4.title span{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

h4.title{
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title"><span>This is a heading</span></h4>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! So obvious and simple.

Comment: @NielsPilon Its my pleasure! Don't forget to accept this as your answer once you are allowed.

Comment: Will, do, 8 minutes left ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the `:after` pseudo selector on the span and apply the green border to the parent `h4`.

```css
h4.title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

h4.title span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h4.title span:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title"><span>This is a heading</span></h4>
```

Comment: Thanks, also a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-image` as well on parent element. Border of the child element will eventually hide the parent background.

```
h4.title {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
}

h4.title span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
h4.title span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

h4.title{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, green) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="title">
  <span>This is a heading</span>
</h4>
```